# Visual Studio 2010 SDK Scan Source files in project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, plugins, extensibility

I'm working with the 2010 SDK and I am trying to figure out how to tie into VS in someway that I have a background process running that is constantly analyzing .CS files in the current project and adding them to a dictionary so I can show some graphical cues in the editor of a custom text document that I have.

I have been doing quite a lot of research here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx

But i cant seem to find a way to "Hook" into VS ...sort of an entry point so this service can run in the background while the project is open.

So far I have an Editor Classifier Project that I have done some modifications to the editor with...how can I monitor files in the background?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `IVsTrackProjectDocumentsEvents2` interface to listen to project events such as adding a file to a project.

`OnAfterAddFilesEx`, `OnAfterRemoveFiles`, and `OnAfterRenameFiles` are the methods you'll be interested in.